# Django admin throws error after installing tastypie?

Tags: django, django-admin, tastypie

When I try to create a new user, I get: `no such table: tastypie_apikey`. Does anyone know why this is happening? The tastypie documentation doesn't refer to any database tables that need to be created, or indeed a way to get tastypie to make any such changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you added `tastypie` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and launched `manage.py syncdb` to create tastypie tables into the database (there are 2: `tastypie_apiaccess` & `tastypie_apikey`).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've been using south, which I thought superceded syncdb.

Comment: I've done this and it still doesn't work for me. I also had a problem during South migration that the `.egg` file wasn't unzipped, so I unzipped it manually and that error went away, but this error still occurs.

Comment: Ok, so there's a workaround here, but this is an underlying issue with South and TastyPie: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/195

Answer (score 6):

OK, I had a similar issue, but it wasn't solved by the solution given by @manji.

The problem has to do with Django and the use of the `create_api_key` signal. `syncdb` will create the user first before tastypie is able to create its tables.

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Wrap your signal in your model with a `try/except` statement like:

   ```
   try:
       models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
   except Exception, e:
       pass
   ```
2. Run `./manage.py syncdb --migrate`
3. Run `./manage.py backfill_api_keys`

Here's the issue on GitHub for your reference: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/195